# Can't start Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I want to process the request with the controller without any logic inside only to return html page. Here the class with configurations and starter class:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/webapp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("NewPage");
}
}


public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { MVCConfig.class };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[] { "/" };
}

}
```

Apparently that's not enough to do it because when trying to get the page in browser I recieve 404 error.
 What do I must to add or change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just to remind you that except the configuration must be complicated,u also need to publish your project as a war and deploy to Tomcat or whatever.
(how to package project as a war,such as maven,use the command "package")
Hope that will help.